# Backbone js setting header for get request

Tags: backbone.js, get, header, request, token

How can I set a header for my token to send GET request to an external url?
I don't want to override the Backbone.sync actually
I want to manually set it for fetching my collection
where should I put the header?

**Specific question:**
 I want to send GET request and I have specific URL I should set the token for that how should I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give custom headers in the `headers` parameter in the `options` to the collection's `fetch` method:

```
var ThingCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/things'
});

var thingCollection = new ThingCollection();
thingCollection.fetch({ 
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic NAME:PASSWORD'
  } 
});
```

Comment: dear @Tholle I want to send GET request and I have specific URL 
I should set the token for that
how should I do that?